# Постинг на стену вконтакте

Tags: вконтакте

Можно ли удаленному скрипты, php например, постить на стену пользвателя вконтакте? 
Есть разговор, что это могут делать только приложения вконтакте?
Наведите пожалуйста.

Comment: На хабре была такая тема, поищи...

Comment: Спасибо) нужно было с хабра начинать: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/social_networks/125155/

Answer (score 3):

Да, ваш скрипт может постить сообщения на стену вконтакте. Но! Для этого необходимо написать приложение, которое будет запрашивать у пользователя права для выполнения подобной функции. Т.е. когда ваш скрипт попробует первый раз это сделать - необходимо авторизовать разрешение на действие, а уже потом в этом отпадёт необходимость. Глубоко в настройках пользовательского аккаунта будет храниться информация о вашем приложении и о том, что оно имеет права доступа для работы со стеной. Разграничение прав доступа подробно описано в API.